# Is there any jquery plugin similar to extjs suberboxselect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, extjs

I am looking for a jquery plugin which is similar to extJS superboxselect extenstion.
Which allows multiselect and autocomplete functions together combined with cool interface.
Any ideas ?

http://www.technomedia.co.uk/SuperBoxSelect/examplesRemote.html

http://www.technomedia.co.uk/SuperBoxSelect/examples3.html

Answer (score 2):

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf

Answer (score 1):

Chosen.js  - http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Select2.js - http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/ (Just like chosen, but with more features)

Answer (score 0):

Not the same view but has pretty much the same functionality http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectCheckboxMenu.jsf